# MySQL Need to show 0 when no value in right hand table of join, with cumulative

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table with a list of number of sales per month against product code and another with a list of months that can extend before or after the months that had a sale in. I need to results to show 0 sales if there were no sales in the month and for the cumulative to add this up. I have tried using case and if and getting it to put 0 if sales.sales was null but this did not work and I still just had blanks.

```
    create table summary as (SELECT
   q1.productid As productid,
   q1.date AS Month_View,
   q1.sales AS Monthly_Units_Sold,
   (@runtot_sales := @runtot_sales + q1.sales) AS Cumulative_Sales
FROM
   (SELECT
   sales.productid,
dates.date,
if(sales.date is null,0,sales.sales) as sales
from
dates 
left join sales on dates.date = sales.date
where
sales.productid = '$input1'
group by dates.date
    ORDER  BY date) AS q1);
    ";
```

Comment: Blanks as in whitepsace or blanks as in still NULL values?

Comment: What is the type of `sales.date` and `dates.date`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `COALESCE()` function to return the first non-NULL value of a list [*Also see demo here*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29518)

```
CREATE TABLE summary AS 
(SELECT 
  q1.productid AS productid,
  q1.date AS Month_View,
  q1.sales AS Monthly_Units_Sold,
  (
    @runtot_sales := @runtot_sales + q1.sales
  ) AS Cumulative_Sales 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    sales.productid,
    dates.date,
    COALESCE(sales.sales, 0) AS sales 
  FROM
    dates 
    LEFT JOIN sales 
      ON dates.date = sales.date 
  WHERE sales.productid = '$input1' 
  GROUP BY dates.date 
  ORDER BY DATE) AS q1) ;
```

[**MySQL COALESCE() function**](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php)

Comment: I think the OQ is looking for `sales.sales` values where you've suggested `COALESCE(sales.date, 0) AS sales`

Comment: Thank you, using this method and moving the where clause to a different temporary table it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing `GROUP BY` and therefore getting indeterminate results. See this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

If you're aggregating your items by product and date you probably want something like this.

```
SELECT sales.productid,
       dates.date,
       SUM(sales.sales) as sales
  FROM dates
  LEFT JOIN sales ON dates.date = sales.date
 WHERE sales.productid = '$input1'
 GROUP BY sales.productid, dates.date
 ORDER BY /* i'm not sure what you're trying to do with the running total */
```

Note that `SUM(sales.sales)` handles the NULL values from your `LEFT JOIN` correctly. If the date doesn't join a sales row then sales.sales will be NULL.

If you're trying to do a month-by-month summary you need more logic than you have.  See this writeup: http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/